# IBM BPM 8.5.6 Client-Side human service visibility script

Tags: response, visibility, client-side, ibm-bpm

I have a table that when I select one or more rows and click a button I go to a service that when finish remove those rows from the table. My problem is that button must appear when I select one or more rows otherwise disappear.
My visibility script for the button is:

```
if(local.get("pSuspendedTasks").get("listAllSelected")[0] == null){
    return "HIDDEN";
}
return "DEFAULT";
```

When I call the service and return without the rows that I selected before the button still there.

NOTE: I use responsive coaches toolkit

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the selection items on the list `pSuspendedTasks`.

You can do it calling method `listClearAllSelected` on server side as below:

```
tw.local.pSuspendedTasks.listClearAllSelected()
```

To works fine, don't forget to pass and return the entire list to the service.

Regards,
Bernardo Baumblatt.